# Are DB modelling review questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion

For example:

> I have a problem P and to solve it I have designed this schema S. Do you see any problems with this design? If yes, what would you change to fix/improve it?

Comment: If you find the suggested duplicates do not sufficiently address your question, please edit your question to clarify.